# Agents instead of dimensions in system dynamics stocks

Tags: anylogic, stock, dimensions, agent, systemdynamics

Currently I have a stock of Grade 1 learners. The stock is arrayed so that `Gr1_learners[..] = {10,10}` means that there are 10 high performing learners and 10 low performing learners in this stock. These learners progress to Grade 2 so that `Gr2_learners[..] = {20,0}` are the first graders having progressed after one year and some intervention improved all the learners to high performing.

My idea is to create learners as agents and place them in the stocks. Then `Gr1_learners = 20` is a stock with 20 agents, half in state `high_performing`, and half in state `low_performing`. They progress, a state change is triggered so that `Gr2_learners = 20` is then a stock with 20 agents, all in state `high_performing` and none in state `low_performing`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by not using stocks at all. You are probably familiar with SD modelling and now see the benefit of agent-based modelling.

Go all in and model your agents. Instead of stocks, you use agent populations and make your agents change states.

See the agent example models, especially the SIR one (there is an SD version and an ABM version, great to see how you can model any SD model with agents)

But you cannot have agents inside SD stocks, they are not actual stocks but just mathematical equations :)